# Invalid markup with XFBML and RDFa

Tags: html, doctype, xhtml, rdfa

EDIT: I switched back to XHTML 1.0 Transitional. It renders fine, but isn't valid. Help is still appreciated.

Hello.

I am trying to integrate the Facebook plugins into my website, [PlugB](http://www.plugb.com/). To make them validate at W3 validator, I added a XHTML + RDFa doctype. But I am getting errors with Iframes and FBML.

How can I fix this?

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.plugb.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the +RDFa part. It's still invalid, but it compiles correctly.